# redis del operation cause slow log

Tags: redis, bloom-filter

Recently, I met a problem when I use setbit in redis. As I use redis as a bloomFilter part for store, 0.2 billion data cost 380MB memory for 99.99% accuracy. Every day I need to delete the redis key for bloomfilter and create a new one, but found slow log, and this may affect other service in product environment. Counld anybody give a better suggest what to do to forbid this? thx a lot~

according command costs(ms):

```
DEL bloomFilterKey 
use(microseconds)：83886
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freeing the large mount of memory, i.e. 380MB, costs too much time, and blocks Redis.

In order to avoid this, you can upgrade your Redis to version `4.0`, and use the new command `UNLINK` to delete the key. This command frees memory in a different thread, and won't block Redis.

Comment: thanks a lot, i read the command from redis.io, and it do helps. But recently we may not upgrade the redis version in product environment. Also, thanks a lot.